# Is there some syntactic sugar for matching on deeply nested Option and Result chains?

Tags: syntax, rust

I am issuing calls that return an `Option` that contains a `Result` which contains another `Option` that contains custom variants.
I am only ever interested in a specific chain of variant results like this:

```
if let Some(Ok(Some(CustomVariant(Some(value))))) = expr {
    // handle value case
}
```

This is getting quite verbose and not really helpful, since I actually treat it as a single `Result` in all of my code. Can I somehow alias this code so that instead of writing the entire chain of `Option`s and `Result`s I can do something similar to:

```
alias TheCase(value) = Some(Ok(Some(CustomVariant(Some(value))));
if let TheCase(value) = expr {
    //handle value
}
```

Comment: I would say a `Option<Result<Option<_>, _>>` is not an adequate structure. Try unwrapping it beforehand with the `?` operator

Comment: That is not what i want, I just want a shorter way of expression the exact combination of Variants, because in just that case i have to do something, otherwise I do not need to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need such an alias, just use a function to retrieve the one case you want:

```
fn oneCaseICareAbout(value: &Option<Result<Option<Foo>, Bar>>) -> Option<&Foo> {
    if let Some(Ok(Some(CustomVariant(Some(value)))) = value {
        Some(value)
    } else {
        None
    }
}

if let Some(value) = oneCaseICareAbout(expr) {
    //handle value
}
```

---

I would however consider refactoring your code not to use such a type. `Option<Result<_, _>>` is already a red flag, but `Some(Ok(Some(CustomVariant(Some(…))))` is just on the edge of insanity!

Comment: Upvote for *"I would however consider refactoring your code"* (TIL I cannot post +1 in the beginning of a comment)

Comment: @hellow That is because commenting on your vote is considered noise, and can be removed from the site. ;)

Comment: Oh believe me, I am itching to refactor myself. But I actually gave it a shot and I cannot understand the codebase nearly good enough to start refactoring it. This structure is returned from a library call from a crate  I am using, and I wish i had the time and skill to rewrite it.